# load and performance test of the AWS API in jmeter using two post methods

Tags: rest, jmeter

I need to test the load and performance test of the API which is hosted in the AWS API gate way. Im using two post methods to get the final result. first post method will pass the below parameters in json format in the API.

{
propno:"xxxxx",
apikey:"xxxx-xxxx",
user:"xxx"
}

by executing this i will get a reference number and status of the execution
{
reference:"ABxxxxxxxxxna",
status:"ok"
}
Then will pass this reference no in another post method to get the desired result.

{
refno:"ABxxxxxxxxxna",
apikey:"xxxx-xxxx",
user:"xxx"
}

Now i want to perform the load test in Jmeter. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your question exactly?

In JMeter you can send a POST request using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, the relevant configuration would be something like:

[image]

the `refno` value can be fetched using [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor) configured like:

[image]

next in the second HTTP Request use `${refno}` reference to the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

[image]

You might also need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send the [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Metadata_and_schema)

[image]

once done you can

1. [Add more users in the Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users) according to your NFR/SLA/common sense/whatever
2. Run your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
3. [Generate HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) and analyze the results